# Converting a simple table from SQL to Redis using Node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, express, redis, node-redis

Suppose I have a SQL table that contains an field called userid (unique,Primary key, autoincrement), Username (varchar), and password (Varchar).

Now suppose I want to recreate this table in Redis. From my understanding, it's best to use a "hash" for this table. Thus my node.js code has a function that creates a user:

```
function newUser(username,password)
{
    //incr the userid
    client.incr("userid",redis.print);

    //Creating the user
    client.get('userid',function(err,userid){
       client.hmset("users", "id",userid,"name",username,"password",password);
    });

}
```

Is this correct?

Also, how do I access the information stored in his hash? I try the following but am only able to return 1 row:

```
client.hgetall('users',function(err,user){
   console.log('User Name: ' + user.name +" password = "+user.password);
})
```

Lastly, how would I join 2 hashes (like I would for 2 tables that needed to be joined?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first Redis is very flexible, so you can key names and data structure to use for users, try not approach this thinking in structured way like mySQL.

an integer to keep track of the user id.

`global:index:users`

storing user password as a string

`user:<id>:password`

storing user information in a hash

`user:<id>`

`name=>username`

`email=>user email`

`some other key=>some other data`

get userid by password, since we don't want to look entire `user:<id>` to get who's password is it.

`user:<passwordHash>:id`

of

`user:<name>:id`